# HashSet doesn't contain my custom object even though I override equals(Object o)

Tags: java

Why is the output of this program `false`? I am expecting `true` as n object initialize with same string what I am checking for.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Name n = new Name("jyoti", "meher");
        Set<Name> s = new HashSet();
        s.add(n);
        System.out.println(s.contains(new Name("jyoti", "meher")));
    }
}

class Name {
    String name, title;

    public Name(String name, String title) {
        this.name = name;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof Name)) {

            return false;
        }
        Name n = (Name) o;
        return n.name.equals(name) && n.title.equals(title);
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overriding equals and hashCode in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the correct output true you need to override the [hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) method in the Name Class

Answer (score 11):

You have to override `hashCode()` too, not just `equals()`.

Answer (score 2):

If two objects have different hashCode values then they will be considered not equal by a `HashSet`.

Whenever you override equals you should also override `hashCode()` to ensure it is consistent. This is particularly important when dealing with `HashSet` and `HashMap` which rely on the hash code to distribute objects.

You can make your code work with the following (non-optimal) implementation of hashCode:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return 1;
}
```

This will force the `HashSet` to use your `equals()` method when comparing your `Name` objects. If you used both `name` and `title` when generating the hash code then there would be less occasions when the equals method would have to be used.

Answer (score 1):

In the Name class both equal and hashcode method should override.so that output will be true.

Answer (score 0):

You should override equals() and hashcode() method to ensure the contract is satisfied to use your object as a key in the implementations like HashSet and HashMap.

You have overridden equals correctly. You can override hashcode also like below

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result
            + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + id;
    result = prime * result
            + ((title == null) ? 0 : title.hashCode());
    return result;
}
```

Overriding hashcode facilitates your object to be stored in different slots based on the hashcode which makes your search faster.

Hope this helps